# Citation display: from "Author (2010), Author (2011)", to "Author (2010, 2011)"

Tags: bibliographies

I am using natbib for my bibliography. I have two papers by the same authors in different years, let's say Tizio & Caio (2010) and Tizio & Caio (2011). Is there an automated way to quote both of them as Tizio & Caio (2010, 2011) ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx! Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) of your input.

Answer (score 2):

Natbib does that out of the box; just use `\citet` with two keys as argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}

\citet{TiCa10,TCa11}

\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem[Tizio \& Caio(2010)]{TiCa10} Tizio \& Caio (2010)

\bibitem[Tizio \& Caio(2011)]{TCa11}Tizio \& Caio (2011)
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a rather simple way to do it by hand

```
\citeauthor{key1} (\citeyear{key1},\citeyear{key2})
```

It should be possible to define a command, say \citeauthoryears, that iterates over a list of keys to give the years, but I am not that profound in tex

Edit: I am not familiar with author-year style, but the cheat sheet ( http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php ) suggests that what you want is default behaviour?